# Sympy Rationals - express (x + 3 )**6/ 6

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, sympy

I'm not able to do this and I'm not sure why? When I enter:

```
x = symbols('x')
exp = Rational((x+3)**6, 6)
```

I'm given a Type_Error.

---

This stems from trying to integrate `(x + 3)**5` and expecting the result of  `(x+3)**6 / 6`

Comment: did you check what is in 'x'?

Comment: @galaxyan x is just a symbol - I'll edit the OP to show this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type `Rational` in Sympy represents a rational number, not a polynomial over the rational numbers;  see the [documentation](http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.1/modules/core.html#rational).  Simply use division instead:

```
p = (x + 3) ** 6 / 6
```